# Bigbluebutton - Invalid BigBlueButton Endpoint and Secret

Tags: docker, bigbluebutton

My BBB secret is valid and is the same for Greenlight .env file.

All of a sudden, I got the error

> Server Error - Invalid BigBlueButton Endpoint and Secret

and when I run:

```
docker run --rm --env-file .env <container-image> bundle exec rake conf:check
```

I get:

```
Checking environment: Passed
Checking Connection: Failed
Error connecting to BigBlueButton server - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (certificate has expired)
```

I have manually updated the certificate of my Ubuntu server but the error still persists. My BBB version 2.2.9.

While browsing online, I read that you have to log into your container using bash by typing:

```
docker exec -it <container-id> /bin/bash
```

and trying to download a certificate (somewhere they was mentioned *https://curl.haxx.se* but I am not 100% sure about the URL). However `curl` in the docker container also complains about an SSL error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused because of an expired Let's Encrypt SSL certificate. More information can be found [here](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/). Removing the certificate and updating the certificates resolves the issue.